# Calculating mean between two dates

Tags: r, datatable, mean

I have a data table with columns date, stock, daily return, start date, and end date.

I'd like to calculate the mean of daily return between start date and end date specific to each stock, where `end date=date`, and `start date=date-1 year`. The image is a small part of my data table, which contains 5 different time brackets `(2009-2010, 2010-2011...2014-2015)`.

[image]

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbRzu.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: As in your data the start date values are absent, you can't calcualte any daily return.

Comment: "D" represents the daily return value that I want to find the mean of. So I tried something like dt[,meanreturn:=mean(D), by=stock], but I'm not sure what to put in the mean() to let it know to only find mean for D values between start and end date.

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you expect? Maybe show us an example of the output desired.

Comment: I think I get what you are asking, but I am unsure of the time-frames you are calculating it for: 2009-2010, what dates specifically?

Comment: I'm looking for a rolling fiscal mean: so I want to take all the daily returns from April 7, 2009 to April 7, 2010 and calculate the mean, then calculate mean(daily returns) for April 8, 2009 to April 8, 2010, etc for the entire dataset. Then assign that mean(daily return) to the corresponding end date.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create the dataset:

```
d1 <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2009-04-07"), as.Date("2015-04-06"), by = "day"), stock = 60004)
d2 <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2009-04-07"), as.Date("2015-04-06"), by = "day"), stock = 60005)
d3 <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2009-04-07"), as.Date("2015-04-06"), by = "day"), stock = 60006)
d4 <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2009-04-07"), as.Date("2015-04-06"), by = "day"), stock = 60007)

dat <- rbind(d1, d2, d3, d4)

dat$D <- rnorm(dim(dat)[1])
dat$stock <- as.factor(dat$stock)

datzoo$rollmean <- ave(dats$D, datzoo$stock, FUN = function(x) rollmean(x, k = 365, fill = 0, align = "right"))
```

For `ave` to work optimally, you should convert `stock` into a factor, and set the `ave` function where `k` is the window size (365 for rolling mean by day); `fill` is what to fill `NA` values with; and `align` is to let the function know which side (left is the same as top and right is the same as bottom of dataset) to calculate your rolling mean from.